# Regex that matches only dirnames with integers and dots

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression

Trying to write `-regex` for a `find` statement that shows only directories with dots and numbers, for example 1.2.3.4 oraz 1.2.3 or 1.3.4.5.6 was trying something like  `"-regex '\.[0-9.]+'"`, but it also shows dirs with letters. And I only want directories with numbers and dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-regex` matches the whole path:

```
find /path -type d -regex ".*/[0-9.]+"
```

Comment: But doesn't it allows letters on other positions?

Comment: You mean inside the path? Yes, this will find any directory which has only `[0-9.]` in its **name**, regardless of the path. If you want to match `[0-9.]` in the whole path use `-regex "[0-9./]+"` instead.

Comment: It's like, I have directory which contains other directories for example something.txt something2.txt 1.2.3.4 5.6.8 4.3.2 and I want to show only those which contains only numbers and dots But both answers show's me also directories with characters...

Comment: Sorry, I've eddited last comment :)

Comment: Your code is working, don't know why in first place it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Standardly:

```
LC_ALL=C find /path ! -name '*[!0-9.]*' -type d
```

That is, list files of type directory whose name doesn't not contain a character other than decimal digit or `.`.